# Filtering a vb.net forms datagridview combo box based on another datagridview combo box value

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Working on a legacy VB.NET windows forms app with a databound DataGridView that has two databound combo boxes.  The first combo box lists products and the second lists companies that make those products.

The company dropdown lists all companies, however when the user adds a new line to the grid they will select a product, at that point I want to filter the company combo (on that row) to show only companies that can make that product. If they edit a line and select a different product, I want to apply a new filter to the company combo box as well.

Option 1:
I have a change handler on the product combo where I pull in product data, I also retrieve a list of company id’s that can make that product, and I can access the company combo box from that row obviously, so at that point I have all the info I need but I do not know how to apply a filter to the datagridview company combo.

```
Dim cbo As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = MyDataGridView.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(ColIndex)
```

Option 2:
I’m using datasets with SQL queries to populate the combo boxes and it occurred to me there may be a way to pass the product selected from the first combo box (which would be the cell value I suppose) to the company combo box dataset as a parameter, then it seems it would all work automagically, but I don’t know how to do that either (if it is even possible).

Any thoughts, solutions, or reference links appreciated!

Comment: Plenty of options to skin that cat.  Really depends on how you've bound/created the list for the companies combo.  If bound, you could possibly get away with simply adding a filter to the binding source.  Or you could execute a query with a parameter & where clause to retrieve the applicable companies, then recreate/reset the list source.  But how to implement this, you will really need to update your question with a lot more context

Comment: I have a dataset that selects all companies that is then bound to the company combo in the datagriveview designer's edit columns popup, I could parameterize that query with a product id and I would then want each row to pass in it's selected product id. That's the part I'm not sure how to do. Can I grab the combo box's datasource in the change event and add the parameter or do I need to create a new data source for each row? I'm sure I can work it out in any case.

Comment: You can use the DVG CurrentRow method to get the focused row, then from there you can call Cells(ColumnIndex) to get the cell and check the Value property